# two stage rotation runtime error

Tags: xcode, git

I'm getting this error in Xcode on runtime.

`Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.`

I do have

Other developers pulled the same code, and it works for them, not on my laptop. So I'm worried about making any changes. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of iOS is higher than theirs. Because, a number of iOS methods (`didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, etc) where deprecated, when you run the code you get the runtime warning but they don't see it.  Note that you might all have the same actual iOS installed but their and your compilation targets may differ.  This can happen with the same GIT code base if certain of your Xcode configuration files are not under version control.  (It is common to configure GIT under Xcode to avoid some Xcode files; your configuration of GIT might have overdone files to avoid - leading to missing the target build specification.)

Ensure that project.pbxproj is under source control (and that xcuserdata is not).  Both are located in the .xcodeproj folder (seen using 'Show Package Contents').